# Looping in RadGrid

Tags: c#, foreach, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm retrieving the List of values using `datatable` and bind it on `RadGrid` with combo  box controls in windows forms.

Questions:

> 1. How I'm going to retrieve each combo box values in my datatable?

Here's my codes:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in RadGrid.Rows) //error here -- 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: isn't the error clear? It is saying you cannot convert `GridViewRowInfo` to `DataGridViewRow`

Comment: yup, i can't find a solution.. T.T I need to loop the radgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about the Telerik grid, but from the error you show it appears that their rows aren't DataGridViewRow's, and are instead GridViewRowInfo.

Rewrite your code like this and see if it helps:

```
foreach (Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo row in RadGrid.Rows)
{
    foreach (Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellInfo cell in row.Cells)        
    {

    }
}
```

Notice that they use their own data types for rows and cells. The error you were getting was telling you that you can't cast from WinForms grid types to Telerik grid types. See [this documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-cells-iterating-cells.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Wont this work??

```
comboBox1.Items.add(cell.Value.ToString());
```

If you r retrieving..

```
cell.value = comboBox1.Items[cell.RowIndex];
```

Comment: how did you get cell?

Comment: What's that cell? where does it come from?